# Show certain part of a different webpage into mine

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to show the top 10 players on my server from gametracker.com into my webpage. 
Now I looked up the source code of the gametracker.com page which is showing the top 10 players and the part looks like this

```
<div class="blocknew blocknew666">
        <div class="blocknewhdr">
            TOP 10 PLAYERS <span class="item_text_12">(Online &amp; Offline)</span>
        </div>
        <table class="table_lst table_lst_stp">
            <tr>
                <td class="col_h c01">
                    Rank
                </td>
                <td class="col_h c02">
                    Name
                </td>
                <td class="col_h c03">
                    Score
                </td>
                <td class="col_h c04">
                    Time Played
                </td>
            </tr>
            .
            .
            .
            .
        </table>
        <div class="item_h10">
        </div>
<a class="fbutton" href="/server_info/*.*.*.*:27015/top_players/">
            View All Players &amp; Stats
        </a>
    </div>
```

As you can see the content I want is within the `class="blocknew blocknew666"` I could have easily pulled it out if it was within an id but I don't know how to handle it when the content is within a class. I looked up on the internet a bit and came across this

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Is it possible to use this code to do what I want? If yes please write the line of code i would need to use, or give me some suggestion on how to tackle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on **tremor's** suggestion this is the working code for the above problem

```
    <?php

function rstrstr($haystack,$needle)
    {
        return substr($haystack, 0,strpos($haystack, $needle));
    }

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/*.*.*.*:27015/');
$topten = strstr($html, 'TOP 10 PLAYERS');//this will print everthing after the content you looked for.
$topten = strstr($topten, '<table class="table_lst table_lst_stp">');
$topten = rstrstr($topten,'<div class="item_h10">'); //this will trim stuff that is not needed
echo $topten;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm only going to post a partial answer because I believe that doing this might be a violation of the terms of use for the GameTracker service, what you are asking for is basically a method to steal proprietary content from another website. You SHOULD most definitely be GETTING PERMISSION from GameTracker before you do this.

To do this I would use strstr. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.gametracker.com/server_info/someip/');
$topten = strstr($html, 'TOP 10 PLAYERS');
echo $topten; //this will print everthing after the content you looked for.
```

Now I will leave it up to you to figure out how to chop off the un-needed content that comes after the top ten is done AND to get permission from GameTracker to use this.

Comment: I understand but the thing is the top players are from my server so i feel like i am justified in getting the list of top 10 players that are playing in my game server

Comment: @RickRoy If they're playing on your game server, why do you need an external source to track them?

Comment: I am not sure how to handle the feed from AMX mod to get the list of top players, and it seemed easier to hack around and get the data from gametracker.com than learning how to pull data from AMX

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is part of the simpledom library

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You need to download and include the library for the code to work.

Comment: Yes I saw that and so modified the code to use `file_get_contents` as I only intend to get the content and dont care if it is in xml so it works for this situation